# How can I test my app on phoneapp XDK

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, phonegap-plugins, appmobi

I'm doing a small program with sencha touch. I deployed it on my webserver (WAMP) and it's working correctly.

Now I want to test it on a smartphone simulator. I searched and I found appMobi PhoneGap XDK, but I do not know  how to incorporate my work in this simulator. Or do you know another simulator to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing your project into the appMobi PhoneGap XDK is pretty easy.  First, create a new application in the XDK.  You can do that from the big, round plus sign button in the upper left hand corner.

[image]

Next, open the project from your project list.  Click on the grey folder icon to open your project folder.

[image]

Finally, drop your PhoneGap bundle (all the HTML,JavaScript, Images, etc) into the root of that folder.  The PhoneGap XDK should start by opening the index.html file in that folder.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you can test your app on android, iphone, windows phone emulators
here are the necessary steps for each http://phonegap.com/start

Comment: thank you for youre response. but have you an idea about appMobi PhoneGap XDK ?

Comment: actually i just discovered it ( thanks to you :p ) and it seems very interesting

Comment: :) if you know how implement my work (sencha touch) into it, tell me :)